# How do I trigger a reaction when bind:this is used in {#await} in Svelte?

Tags: async-await, svelte

Let us say that I want to have a little UI overlay that points to a DOM element (let us call it "Tap Here"). To get the location of where it should point to: I use bind:this and it works, unless I don't use it in {#await}.

```
<script>
    import TapHere from './TapHere.svelte';
    let enableButton;
    $: enableButtonRect = enableButton && enableButton.getBoundingClientRect();

    let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setInterval(resolve, 3000);
    });
</script>

{#await promise}
<p>
    waiting...
</p>
{:then}
<div>
  <button bind:this={enableButton}>Enable</button>
  <button>Disable</button>
  <TapHere rect={enableButtonRect}/>
</div>
{/await}
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/4e0e477d6a394a83a2d79b3d1fa50525?version=3.12.1

(enableButtonRect may be a bit of red-herring as this problem manifests it with just trying to pass in enableButton itself to TapHere.)  If you remove await, the TapHere goes to the intended location; but with await, TapHere does not get triggered by the enableButtonRect change. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow `enableButton` is `undefined` **within the promise resolve block** even after the promise resolves.

However, if you evaluate `enableButton` **outside of the block**, it is correctly `undefined` while the promise is still pending, and correctly set to `[object HTMLButtonElement]` once the promise resolves.

There must be an explanation for this behavior, but I do not know it. Hopefully someone can elaborate.

So you can achieve the result you want by moving the `<TapHere>` component outside the promise block:

```js
<script>
  import TapHere from './TapHere.svelte';
  let enableButton;
  $: enableButtonRect = enableButton && enableButton.getBoundingClientRect();
    
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setInterval(resolve, 3000);
  });
</script>

{#await promise}
<p>
  waiting...
</p>
{:then}
<div>
  <button bind:this={enableButton}>Enable</button>
  <button>Disable</button>
</div>
<p>Inside promise resolve block: {enableButton}</p>
{/await}
<p>Outside promise resolve block: {enableButton}</p>
<TapHere rect={enableButtonRect}/>
```

#### Edit

To show the tooltip after a promise resolves, you could do the following:

```js
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import TapHere from './TapHere.svelte';
  let enableButton;
  let disabled = true;
  $: enableButtonRect = enableButton && enableButton.getBoundingClientRect() && !disabled;
    
  onMount(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => { disabled = false }, 3000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  })
</script>

<div>
  <button bind:this={enableButton} {disabled}>Enable</button>
  <button>Disable</button>
  <TapHere rect={enableButtonRect}/>
</div>
```

(REPL updated)

https://svelte.dev/repl/e647bc2b1a024e8885ebb96317887710?version=3.12.1

Comment: Thanks.  What I really want is that the TapHere guy shows up when "it's ready" (that is, in this simplified example it is the interval fires), so ideally TapHere won't be shown until then, and only then start its moving transition.  (I can write that logic but it would have been much simpler if I can just wrap the entire thing in #await.

Comment: Oh, so you mean - staying with a simple example - initially show the buttons in a disabled state, and after the interval (i.e. when the promise resolves) show the tooltip while enabling the button?

Comment: I think the original problem is that when you place `bind:this` (which creates a DOM reference) within an `#await` block, then *use* that reference within the same block, the code making use of the reference is evaluated before the entire block is actually rendered, hence the reference is not yet valid. Which I believe makes sense.

Comment: It is okay that there is a time when that reference is undefined. but when the element is actually created and the bind:this updates the variable, the elements that depends on the variable should update; as it does when the entire div is not encloed by {#await}.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was trying to say. By the time `bind:this` updates `enableButton`, you have *already* evaluated `enableButtonRect` for the same update cycle  because `<TapHere>` is rendered within the same promise block. It's a race condition of sorts. At least that's my take on it.

Comment: Note that enableButtonRect is not essential to illustrate the problem. I can instead pass enableButton itself to TapHere, and TapHere can then call getBoundingClientRect() to get the rect.. but the result is the same.  And again, why would wrapping the entire thing with {#await} change the behavior if the race-condition you mentioned is the actual issue? My mental model is there is that, either with or withour {#await}, once the DOM tree construction would be done in the same manner once it started, and props would be evaluated in the same manner.